# Keep order of list after filtering

Tags: typescript, sorting, filtering

I have two lists and I am filtering the lists to check if the value exists in both then return this result. But the order of the returned list is different from the original list.

So the orignal list contains - 'calender', 'banker', 'exchange rate', 'campaign'.
The second list contains - 'exchange rate', calender'.

Filtering to create a new list that contains both values returns 'exchange rate', calender'.

It has taken the order of the second list but I want to keep the order from the first list i.e. the result should be 'calender', 'exchange rate'.

This is the code I used to filter:

```
const newList = secondList.filter((f) => !firstList.includes(f));
```

How to I sort the result to keep the order of the first list?

Comment: If you want the interseciton of 2 lists, in the order of the first list, why don't you iterate over the first list: `const newList = firstList.filter((elem) => secondList.includes(elem));`

Comment: Beside what the others said, sorting it can be made with e.g. `newList.sort((a, b) => firstList.indexOf(a) - firstList.indexOf(b))`

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to do the reverse of what you're describing - it would return items from `secondList` that are NOT present in the `firstList`

Just inverse the logic:

```
const newList = firstList.filter((f) => secondList.includes(f));
```

This will filter the items of the first list (hence you will get order from the first list as well), returning only items that are in both lists.

```js
const firstList = ['calender', 'banker', 'exchange rate', 'campaign'];
const secondList = ['exchange rate', 'calender'];

const newList = firstList.filter((f) => secondList.includes(f));

console.log(newList);
```